# Is there a reference for WinUI 3 XAML?

Tags: windows, xaml, winui-3

I am trying to get up to speed on building modern windows apps, having not done so since the glory days of .NET Forms.

I'm trying to learn WinUI 3 (0.8 reunion), and what's tripping me up is that there doesn't seem to be a cohesive reference anywhere. A place that will tell me what elements can go inside which elements in an XAML file and such, so I can know immediately by reading a reference that, for example, you can't put a `<Span>` inside a `<RichTextBlock>`, without having to see weird esoteric errors.

There are scattered examples around MS's website but not a single resource that I've been able to find that encompasses all of it in a clear fashion. I can look up RichTextBlock and find out about what properties it has, but nowhere does it give a simple overview of what elements it can contain.

Comment: There cannot be a reference for XAML. After all, it's an object instantiation markup language, that works on arbitrary types, types it cannot know.

Comment: ... but there should be documentation of which types are available and how they work. Or at least, there COULD be.

Comment: How would that work? XAML can instantiate types I authored just moments ago. How do you envision Microsoft to document those types? Remember, those are types Microsoft doesn't know about. If you need to find out which types WinUI exposes then look into the online documentation or the .winmd file that comes with the library.

Comment: If you're looking for samples, those are primarily shipped by way of the [XAML Controls Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/xaml-controls-gallery/xaml-controls-gallery/).

Comment: I would just like microsoft to document their own types. But while we're here, do you know of a guide on how to create your own xaml types? I haven't come across that yet and I need that too.

Comment: Any Windows Runtime type can be instantiated via XAML. I suppose you are interested primarily in using XAML for your UI. [XAML custom (templated) controls with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/xaml-cust-ctrl) provides a good introduction for C++ developers. I'm not familiar with using the Windows Runtime from a managed programming language and cannot recommend anything for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the link from the comment of user IInspectable to the **XAML controls gallery for WinUI** should be at least one of the possible answers, so I decided to post it as an answer myself.
Here are the links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/xaml-controls-gallery/xaml-controls-gallery/
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery

I downloaded the source code (the Visual Studio solution resides in the "XamlControlsGallery" folder), compiled and started it.
It shows the usage of allmost all WinUI controls, so it was quite helpful to me.

This link might also be of help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/

It shows a list of "Controls for Windows apps" and mentions which of them are available in WinUI.